# libhdf5.so.100: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (However, libhdf5.so.100 is in /usr/local/lib)

Tags: shared-libraries, octave, hdf5

Although I can see that `libhdf5.so.100` is actually inside `/usr/local/lib`, I receive the following error when running octave:

> bash-4.3$ octave
>
> /usr/local/bin/octave-cli-4.0.2: error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5.so.100: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I built octave 4.0.2 myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the line `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and then ran `sudo ldconfig`. Problem solved.